# Unit more then one project to one maven project

Tags: java, maven

i have 3 maven project (starto.commons,starto.hibernate,starto.server) that use some same dependencies and two of then use the thread project(commons).

i try to unit the 3 project to one big maven project (lets call him starto.bigMavenProject for the example)

i mean that:

1) every project stay project on its own bat use the starto.bigMavenProject pom for dependencies

2)when i build (run mvn insatll) starto.bigMavenProject it's build the all three project (starto.commons,starto.hibernate,starto.server).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a Maven parent project for your three projects. I'd suggest taking a look at the [POM documentation on inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance) as well as [Sonatype's simple example](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html).

Basically, you want a POM for `start.bigMavenProject` something like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>starto</groupId>
    <artifactId>bigMavenProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <modules>
      <module>commons</module>
      <module>hibernate</module>
      <module>server</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Though you may need to do some additional tweaking to, e.g., your directory structure, etc.

The key thing is your parent POM should have `<packaging>pom</packaging>` and define each sub-project as a module.

Comment: thanks i try this before i post this thread but i guess i missing the <packaging>pom</packaging> and that the parent project should be in parent folder of the other projects (starto.commons,starto.hibernate,starto.server) too, but now it's work thanks to you :-)